# How to extract text from custom flags

Tags: vba, outlook

I handle a number of emails every day. I flag emails with custom text to track emails and correlate each with the other.

How do I extract emails that are flagged along with custom texts in each flagged email in a folder.

I could manage to follow VBA code available at [VBA Express forum](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67187-Outlook-VBA-e-mail-count-per-day&p=401067):

```
Sub CountItems()
    Dim objMainFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim lItemsCount As Long
 
    'Select a folder
    Set objMainFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder
 
    If objMainFolder Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "You choose select a valid folder!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Warning for Pick Folder"
    Else
       'Initialize the total count
       lItemsCount = 0
       Call LoopFolders(objMainFolder, lItemsCount)
    End If
 
    'Display a message for the total count
    MsgBox "There are " & lItemsCount & " items in the " & objMainFolder.Name & " folder Including its subfolders.", vbInformation, "Count Items"
End Sub


Sub LoopFolders(ByVal objCurrentFolder As Outlook.folder, lCurrentItemsCount As Long)
    Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.folder
 
    lCurrentItemsCount = lCurrentItemsCount + objCurrentFolder.Items.Count
 
    'Process all folders and subfolders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count Then
       For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
           Call LoopFolders(objSubfolder, lCurrentItemsCount)
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

It displays the count of emails in a folder and its subfolders.

---

I stumbled across "[How do you access custom Follow-Up flag values (“Flag to…”) in Outlook 2016?](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67187-Outlook-VBA-e-mail-count-per-day&p=401067)" which partially solves my problem.

The solution, from what I could understand, pivots around the Search Folder in Outlook mail client and setting custom view by All Mail fields and Follow Up Flag and then setting the condition of the latter to "**is not empty**". Grouping by "Follow Up Flag" ascending then displays the custom flags in groups for easy reference.

However, that does not solve the problem of listing the custom flag values.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all folder in Outlook and searching for specific items is not really a good idea as shown in your sample code:

```
'Process all folders and subfolders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count Then
       For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
           Call LoopFolders(objSubfolder, lCurrentItemsCount)
       Next
    End If
```

Instead, you may consider using the [AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb219884(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) method of the Outlook `Application` class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The AdvancedSearch method and related features in the Outlook object model do not create a Search Folder that will appear in the Outlook user interface. However, you can use the [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb206972(v=office.12)) method of the Search object that is returned to create a Search Folder that will appear in the Search Folders list in the Outlook user interface.

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- Finally, you can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about that in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

```
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
  If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then
    m_SearchComplete = True
  End If
End Sub


Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()
  Dim Scope As String
  Dim Filter As String
  Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search 
  Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table
  Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row
  m_SearchComplete = False
  'Establish scope for multiple folders
  Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath
& "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"
  'Establish filter
  If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then
    Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"
  Else
    Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"
  End If

  Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")

  While m_SearchComplete <> True
    DoEvents
  Wend

  Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable
  Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable
    Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()
    Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")
  Loop
End Sub
```

Also you may consider using the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods that allow getting items that correspond to the search filter in a specific folder (per folders). Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `.Restrict` on `FlagRequest` to count items with a custom text flag.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountCustomFlagItems()

    Dim objMainFolder As folder
    Dim lItemsCount As Long
    Dim customText As String
    Dim resFilter As String
    Dim uMsg As String
    
    'Select a folder
    Set objMainFolder = Session.PickFolder
    
    If objMainFolder Is Nothing Then
       ' user cancelled
       Exit Sub
    Else
        'Initialize the total count
        lItemsCount = 0
        
        customText = "Custom Text Here"
        
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.flagrequest
        resFilter = "[FlagRequest] = " & customText
        Debug.Print "resFilter: " & resFilter
        
        Call LoopFolders(objMainFolder, lItemsCount, resFilter)
    End If
    
    'Display a message for the total count
    uMsg = "There are " & lItemsCount & " " & customText & " items in the " & objMainFolder.Name & _
      " folder including subfolders."
    
    Debug.Print uMsg & vbCr
    
    'MsgBox uMsg, vbInformation, "Count Items"
    
End Sub


Sub LoopFolders(ByVal objCurrentFolder As folder, lCurrentItemsCount As Long, resFilter As String)

    Dim objSubfolder As folder
    
    Dim objCurrentFolderItems As Items
    Dim resItms As Items
    
    Set objCurrentFolderItems = objCurrentFolder.Items
    
    If objCurrentFolderItems.Count Then
        
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict
        Set resItms = objCurrentFolderItems.Restrict(resFilter)
        
        If resItms.Count Then
            Debug.Print objCurrentFolder & " Items Count: " & objCurrentFolderItems.Count
            Debug.Print " Filtered items in the folder " & objCurrentFolder & ": " & resItms.Count
            Debug.Print
            lCurrentItemsCount = lCurrentItemsCount + resItms.Count
        End If
        
    End If
    
    'Process all folders and subfolders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.folders.Count Then
        For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.folders
            Call LoopFolders(objSubfolder, lCurrentItemsCount, resFilter)
        Next
    End If
    
End Sub
```